# How to make a Pod link from a module to a script within the same distribution?

Tags: perl, perl-pod, metacpan

Consider this module [App::TimeTracker](https://metacpan.org/pod/App::TimeTracker). If you click on the `tracker` link in the `SYNOPSIS` section you end up [here](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/App-TimeTracker/bin/tracker_bash_autocomplete) whereas you should have ended up [here](https://metacpan.org/pod/release/DOMM/App-TimeTracker-3.000/bin/tracker). The Pod source code responsible for the behavior is given [here](https://metacpan.org/release/App-TimeTracker/source/lib/App/TimeTracker.pm#L314), which shows that the following Pod formatting code was used:

```
L<tracker>
```

I can fix the problem by providing an absolute link instead:

```
L<tracker|https://metacpan.org/pod/release/DOMM/App-TimeTracker-3.000/bin/tracker>
```

but this fixes the link to version 3.000 which may change in the future.

So how should this be done in general?

Comment: `https://metacpan.org/release/App-TimeTracker/source/bin/tracker` maybe?

Comment: Hi @choroba, thanks for the suggestion, but it [shows](https://metacpan.org/release/App-TimeTracker/source/bin/tracker) the source code of the script not the Pod documentation

Comment: So https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/App-TimeTracker/bin/tracker ?

Comment: @choroba Yes this works I think :)

Comment: 1) If you're linking within a distribution, you *should* be linking to a specific version. It makes no sense for the local documentation to be for a different version than the one installed. 2) This is an XY problem. The real problem is the creation of two pods with the same name. Fix that, and continue using `L<tracker>`.

Comment: @ikegami Thanks for the comment. I am not sure I understand: *"The real problem is the creation of two pods with the same name"* which two pods did you mean?

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/u6iT6.png If only the second doc existed, surely it would link to it?

Comment: @ikegami Yes, but why did the two files get the same pod name? These two files: [tracker](https://metacpan.org/source/DOMM/App-TimeTracker-3.001/bin/tracker) and [tracker_bash_autocomplete](https://metacpan.org/source/DOMM/App-TimeTracker-3.001/bin/tracker_bash_autocomplete). Is it a bug in metacpan.org or in the source distribution?

Comment: I"m not sure why there are two. I looked a little bit earlier, but nothing jumped out at me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the full path without the version number: [`https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/App-TimeTracker/bin/tracker`](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/App-TimeTracker/bin/tracker).

Comment: This makes no sense! Don't make the local documentation point to something other than the local version. It's bad enough that you require switching from `man`/`perldoc` to a web browser; at least link to the right version.

Comment: @ikegami: Links don't work in my local version of `man` / `perldoc`.

Comment: I have to agree with @ikegami - MetaCPAN has logic to link within the same release of the distribution, but using the full "versionless" link bypasses this ability and will cause the reader to unexpectedly jump versions.

Comment: @choroba, Which brings up an even bigger problem: `man tracker` and `perldoc tracker` bring  up the wrong page. This is particularly bad because you see a link named "tracker".

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that tracker_bash_autocomplete is not being indexed correctly as documentation by MetaCPAN. The `NAME` section has a very specific format based on manpages which must be adhered to for MetaCPAN to know how to link to your documentation. Putting `tracker bash autocomplete` before the hyphen makes MetaCPAN index it as `tracker`.

```
=head1 NAME

tracker_bash_autocomplete - whatever
```

Comment: So spaces are not allowed in the string before the hyphen?

Comment: It's not specifically documented by perlpodstyle or man(7) but I believe this is the case (for each single program). Programs are separated by both a comma and a space.